# Visual Studio 2010 not publishing all of App_Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, webdeploy, app-data

I published my project with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate SP1 and I have a bunch of files in ~/App_Data.

I don't remember if the first upload of appdata was with FTP or with WebDeploy. The problem is when I add new files to ~/App_Data and publish the site, those files (or folders under ~/App_Data) never get published.

My project web deployment settings has the "Exclude App_Data" UNCHECKED so it should be uploading it, yet it doesn't.

Anything else I should do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can happen if you don't have the "Build Action" set to "Content". This can be changed by looking at the properties of the files in question (right click "Properties" on the file).

Answer (score 5):

It can be set as below screenshot. Uncheck the exclude App_Data

[image: Setting Page]

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the *Build Action* in the file properties is set to "Content". <s>, and the *Copy to Output Directory* is set to "Copy if Newer".</s>

Comment: This is on one or more files within the directory, not on the app_data directory itself